# Overridden Model Entities not Executing

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to override the Customer's model entities for Address and Customer. It's working in my development environment but I can't get it to run in production. They're both using Magento 1.6.0.0.

There are two areas I might be getting wrong:

1. It's possible that I haven't uploaded all of the required files but don't know what I've missed. I've tried FTP'ing the whole module directory so if there are additional files they must be from another part of the code.
2. Missing data from/incorrect data in the database. This seems more likely but I'm not sure where to look (I set the data directly via PhpMyAdmin as opposed to using a Magento setup file for this - it's a custom Magento project so won't need to reproduce/replicate this anywhere else in the future.)

Anyway, here's what I've got, in case I'm doing something wrong from a code level.

**Overrides**

```
class Zac_Attack_Model_Entity_Address extends Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Address
{
    protected function _afterSave( Varien_Object $address )
    {
        // this method never gets called.
    }
}

class Zac_Attack_Model_Entity_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Customer
{
    protected function _saveAddresses( Varien_Object $address )
    {
        // this method never gets called.
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<models>
    <customer_entity>
        <rewrite>
            <address>Zac_Attack_Model_Entity_Address</address>
            <customer>Zac_Attack_Model_Entity_Customer</customer>
        </rewrite>
    </customer_entity>
</models>
```

The override is so that we can add third type of primary address to the customer addresses. The attribute is setup correctly in the database for the new address - if I manually set an address to be the 'default_custom' address it shows up in the customer details in both front- and back-end but without the model entity the system won't input the address. If I don't find what's I'm missing I could always move the logic to the various "Save" functions but I would prefer to keep to the approach already adopted by the Magento core code.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a configuration file at `app/etc/modules/*`?

Does that configuration file contain an `<enabled/>` node with a value of `true`?

Does that configuration file contain the name of the correct code pool? (community or local).

Does your module name show up in the Advanced - Disable Output list of of modules?  Have you tried using the [Module List Module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/module-list.html) to debug why it isn't showing up?

Have you tried writing code that instantiates an instance of the model for you and checks that your class name is getting used

```
$model = Mage::getMode('foo/bar');
var_dump(get_class($model));
```

Are you sure the method you're overriding isn't getting called?

Is there another module that's rewritten the same class?

Comment: Hi Alan, good questions. To answer the first few, this is an addition to an existing module which is working in other places. So yes, the module is showing up in the Disable Output list. How do I go about instantiating an entity model (getModel returns the standard model class as opposed to the entity model)? I will search for the answer to that question myself but if you know the answer already you may be faster. Oh, your tutorials on the Magento site were an awesome resorce when I started this, so thanks. ;-)

Comment: When I call getModel( 'customer/entity_address' ) it returns Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Address - so it doesn't appear to be overridden by any other modules. Also, I checked all modules in the Community and Local areas and none of them override the class. I am certain that my method overrides are not getting called - I put some die('...') statements in the overridden methods as well as the base methods. The base methods were called, the overridden ones were not.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your `config.xml` be like:

```
<models>
    <customer>
        <rewrite>
            <entity_address>Zac_Attack_Model_Entity_Address</entity_address>
            <entity_customer>Zac_Attack_Model_Entity_Customer</entity_customer>
        </rewrite>
    </customer>
</models>
```

Comment: Well, that was my original approach - but I had no success with it. I changed my config in line with: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14103/ and it works successfully in my local environment. Just not sure why it's not working in live... I may try this again just to be certain but I think it won't work. Cheers for the answer.

Comment: No luck - it doesn't get overridden. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Maybe a stupid idea, but instead of combining them into one `<rewrite>` have you tried putting each class override it's own `<customer>` tag?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you - are you saying to try a different `<customer><rewrite></rewrite></customer>` node for every different model? Or perhaps a `<customer>` node for the regular models and another node for the entity models?

Comment: I mean `<customer_entity><rewrite><address></address></rewrite></customer_entity>` and then `<customer_entity><rewrite><customer></customer></rewrite></customer_entity>`.